# How to ignore special characters in File Transformation Task of Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am having xyz.config file like below. I have created xyx.Release.config file to use in File Transformation task.

```
 <formatters>

      <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}&#xD;&#xA;Message: {message}&#xD;&#xA;  name="Reduced Text Formatter" />

</formatters>
```

After the  File Transformation task in pipeline it transformed as below. The special characters are replaced after the execution of File Transformation task.

```
<formatters>

        <add template="Timestamp: {timestamp}
```

Message: {message}

-

```
</formatters>
```

Anyone please let me know how to ignore special character transformation as part of File Transformation task.

Thanks in advance.
Mohan

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the File transform task doesn't support to ignore special character transformation.

The file transfrom task will use the built-in method to do the file transform option. It doesn't support to use custom method to do the option.

Here is the doc about the built-in method: [Web.config Transformation Syntax for Web Project Deployment Using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd465326(v=vs.110))

It supports overall replacement of strings, but currently does not support replacing only the part of value in the string and ignoring others.

For a workaround, you can use the replace method then just change the part of value in the string to keep the format of the string.

For example: xyx.Release.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
 <formatters>
     <add template="Timestamp: test1&#xD;&#xA;Message: test2&#xD;&#xA;"  name="Reduced Text Formatter" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(template)"  />
 </formatters>
</configuration>
```